# How to format link in an email from a spreadsheet with AppScript

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that is supposed to send to a client list certain information.

I want the Email to be editable from the Spreadsheet to avoid the end users from having to look at the AppScript code at all.

So I have a cell that looks something like this:

```
To create an order please click <a href='link'>here</a> and follow the instructions.
```

Then I build the email body by calling the different cells that have the relevant info like this:

```
 var messageBegin = ss.getRange('Correo!G1').getValues();
 var messageLink = linkText;
 var messageEnd = ss.getRange('Correo!G11').getValues();
 var message = messageBegin + messageLink + messageEnd;
```

Problem is the email ends up having the HTML code visible instead of a usable link, i.e. literally says: To create an order please click here and follow the instructions.

I'm fairly sure this is a stupid fix but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to make sure that you are sending an email with an `HTML` formatting not  `plain text`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `htmlBody` in GmailApp or MailApp `sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)` [advanced parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#advanced-parameters_1).

[image]

---

**Sample Code:**

```
  var messageBegin = "Good Day,"
  var messageLink = "To create an order please click <a href=www.google.com>here</a> and follow the instructions.";
  var messageEnd = "Thank you,<br>Best Regards"
  var message = messageBegin +"<br><br>"+ messageLink +"<br><br>"+ messageEnd;
  MailApp.sendEmail('sample@email.com','test',"",{htmlBody: message});
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered some issues so i could update the answer accordingly

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! This definitely looks like it should work, but I'm having an issue. Here is my code:
      if (lista == sheetName) {
        console.log("Fila 78: Message sent: "+ message);
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, {htmlBody: message}, {
          attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)],
          name: subject
      });
This is how the console log of the "message" variable looks: 

Text text text 

Text text <a href='link'>text</a> text text

But the email just has:

[object Object]

Comment: htmlBody should be included in your options and let the 3rd parameter be an empty string. `MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, "", {htmlBody: message, attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)], name: subject })`

Comment: Hey! Thanks again for the follow up. I'm a dofus and now it works perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)